# Autofac SingleInstance not disposed when app restarts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, lucene.net

In my MVC4 project I have a lucene `IndexWriter` inside an object I created, which is an IDisposable object called `LuceneIndex`.
When my object is disposed it calls the indexwriter's Dispose() method.
Disposing the IndexWriter deletes a file on disk called `write.lock`.
My LuceneIndex is registered like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<LuceneIndex>()
 .WithParameter("indexLocation", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(UmbracoConfig.IndexPath))
 .SingleInstance();
```

When I stop/recycle/restart the website the write.lock is not deleted, thus from now on I get an exception from lucene like so:

> Message: [LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\Dev\FOO\http\App_Data\Index\write.lock:
>   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Dev\FOO\http\App_Data\Index\write.lock' because it is being used
>   by another process. 
>   ...

Note: The breakpoint in the dispose method is not hit. Should it be?

What is the best way to ensure the IndexWriter is disposed correctly so it does not leave behind the `write.lock`?

Should I be doing something quite different?

Comment: And what happens when there is a power failure?

Comment: Can you show the code in your app where you explicitly dispose of the container before the app restarts?

Comment: @Steven, I'm not sure.... doing some additional testing .... it seems that it's not the presence of the file, but rather the file handles held by the processes that locks write access.... now I'm confused as to why restarting the app pool does not release those file handles regardless of disposal.

Comment: @TravisIllig I didn't have an explicit dispose of the container, but I've now added it. Debug shows it is being called, but my SingleInstance isn't having it's dispose called. The container setup and my added 'OnApplicationEnd' bit is in a dependant assembly from a separate solution, but I don't suppose that matters

Comment: Is `OnApplicationEnd` being called?

Comment: Ok, my bad it is actually working, so the answer was "I need to explicitly call _container.Dispose()" I had mistakenly supposed the MVC integration would deal with that. I've also moved the explicit disposal piece of code to an answer, since that's what fixed it for me. .... now I have a kinda separate problem in that restarting the app, does not end the old one before starting the new one, rather the new one starts first, then the old one is ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispose must be explicitly called on the container, like so:

```
protected override void OnApplicationEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _container.Dispose();
    base.OnApplicationEnd(sender, e);
}
```

On a side note: The application end and the application start overlap such that the ending process still has the `write.lock` file handle when the new process is starting. To deal with this I've simply increased the lucene lock acquisition timeout `WRITE_LOCK_TIMEOUT` to 1 minute to handle those scenarios.